# How can I set an object trough UserControl?

Tags: c#, webforms, user-controls

This is my code:

```
<uc4:RotatorTestata ID="RotatorTestata2" PaginaPer='<%#Eval("myObject")%>' runat="server" />
```

myObject is type `MyObject`.
On the other hand, I have:

```
public MyObject PaginaPer { get; set; }
```

but it are not able to pass that myObject instance. It is always null.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: You need to instantiate that property somewhere for it not to be null.

Comment: Can you provide more context around the code? What is the Item source? Where does myObject defined? etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a function in your code behind and call that function in place of Eval.

```
<uc4:RotatorTestata ID="RotatorTestata2" PaginaPer='<%# GetMyObject()%>' runat="server" />


MyObject GetMyObject()
{
  return myobject instance here. 
}
```

Also you can do it in code behind like

```
RotatorTestata2.PaginaPer = new MyObject();
```

If its inside GridView/Repeater you can catch RowDataBoundEvent and write like

```
Protected void OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{
   var  rotator    e.Row.FindControl("RotatorTestata2") as RotatorTestata ;
   rotator.PaginaPer= new MyObject();
}
```